# How to count black pixels from image in MS Access VBA?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have capture signatures using Msink Obj control from my form and saved them in signature field in my SQL database and datatype for it is image.

I have converted the saved sign data in to .gif and also shown it in image control in my form but now I want to calculate number of black pixels in this image or count of it.

So please suggest how can I go with it?

Answer (score 1):

I have found an windows API for it which can we used for getting pixel count.

It is  GetPixel Lib "gdi32" API below is sample code for it :-

```
Option Compare Database

'Following Two API'S Are Added To Count The Pixles
Private Declare Function GetPixel Lib "gdi32" (ByVal hdc As Long, ByVal X As Long, ByVal y As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function GetWindowDC Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As Long) As Long

Public Function GetPixlesTest(pHwnd As Long) As Integer: On Error Resume Next 
Dim i As Long, j As Long, nBlack As Long, nWhite As Long, pHdc As Long, tempColor As Long
Dim count As Integer

count = 0 'Initializing count with 0

  With Forms!frmTestSign!imgTest 'Getting Form Image Control
        pHdc1 = GetWindowDC(pHwnd)
        For i = 0 To .Width
            For j = 0 To .Height`enter code here`
                tempColor = GetPixel(pHdc1, i, j)
                If tempColor = vbBlack Then 'Counting for black pixles only.
                    nBlack = nBlack + 1
                End If
            Next
        Next
    End With
    TotalBlack = nBlack - 611 'Substracting 611 becuase it has default 611 black pixle on my form
    GetPixlesPractical = TotalBlack
End Function
```

Calling above function :-

```
gstrpixlecount = GetPixlesPractical(Me.hwnd) 'Call it on same form in which you have image control to get pixles.
```

Plesae follow below link for more info :-

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd144947(v=vs.85).aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd144909(v=vs.85).aspx

http://www.vbdotnetforums.com/graphics-gdi/22565-using-winapi-getpixel.html

Thanks